# How do I Trust a Local Folder Windows Vista

Tags: security, windows-vista

I have a folder that was created by unzipping a folder from my `c:\users\<username>\downloads` directory. The folder that was created is now not trusted, is there a way that I can trust this folder.

It is a local folder, not a mapped folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about Vista's ability to "block" files, then just right-click on the file in question, go to Properties, then click Unblock.

To unblock a bunch of files, download and run [streams](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897440.aspx) with the -s option.

Answer (score 1):

If you are opening the files in Office and it is telling you that the location isn't trusted, visit this page for instructions on adding trusted locations:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/HA100319991033.aspx